# How to calculate MISE - Mean Integrated Squared Error?

Tags: probability, statistics

I might have misunderstood something, but it seems like taking a definite integral from expectation or expectation from definite integral. But the first stage will return a number in both cases.

I thought that integral under expectation is indefinite, but it looks like just a "notation" in many places, because further digging brings negative answer - for example: [see § 2.2.4 here](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/spm/spmhtmlnode9.html)
But I have only one variable - $x$, and estimated $\hat{f}(x,h)$ and theoretical $f(x)$ functions.

Can anyone explain me how to calculate $MISE(h) = E \int_{\mathbb{R}}(\hat{f}(x,h)-f(x))^2dx$ ?

I see that there are some further manipulations involving the structure of kernel, but I just want to perform a simple computation in Wolfram having two functions, like

> MISE[ h_ ]:=NIntegrate[ NExpectation [ ...]... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\hat{f}(x,h)-f(x))^2dx$$ is a random variable because your density estimate $$\hat{f}(x,h)$$ depends on your sample. The integral above measures the quality of your estimate by integrating the square of the difference over the reals. The result is still a random number whose expectation can be calculated given that you know the common distribution of your sample.

**Further Information**

Let's consider a specific example. Let $X(i), i=1,2,...n$ be a sequence of independent random variables of a common **known** pdf. Let the common distribution be uniform over the interval $[0,1]$. Say, $n=10$ and the actual sample is 0.2, 0.3, 0.22223, 0.89, 0.565, 0.11, 0.1222, 0.3454, 0.12, 0.0001. Now, you can calculate the density estimate [based on the formula given at your reference](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/spm/spmhtmlnode9.html) if $h$ is given. Then you can calculate the integral in question because you know the common distribution of your samples. Then perform another experiment resulting in another $10$ sample points. You can calculate the integral again; you will get another result. If you repeat this experiment ($10$ samples each time) then the average of the results will tend to the expectation:

$$\mathbb E\left [\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\hat{f}(x,h)-f(x))^2dx \right].$$

Now, you may ask why we estimate the density if we already know it. Please, go back to your [reading](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/spm/spmhtmlnode9.html) and see why the author does all this.

Comment: Suppose I have generated a sample X with N elements? and I have some estimating function like $\hat{f}(x,h)=\frac{1}{Nh}\sum_{i=1}^{N} K(\frac{x-X(i)}{h})$. I still can't understand, how I will get a random variable and calculate an expectation. The integration will return some number that depends on $h$.
If i take an expectation just by multiplying it by density $f(x)$, the number will pass out of the integral which = 1.

Comment: I edit my answer to help you understand what I am saying.

Comment: Thank you! So, I need to generate few samples $X_1, ..., X_m$ with each having $N$ elements, calculate the integral for each one and then take the average between them. The reason why I need to do it is to try different Kernels and compare the result (optimal $h$) with the results obtained from Silverman's rule-of-thumb and minimization of ISE. (AMISE is not mentioned, so I perform this direct calculation).