# What does the 'expected value' E represent in mean integrated squared error (MISE)

Tags: probability, riemann-integration, density-function, mean-square-error

I am trying to use mean integrated squared error (MISE) to determine the optimal parameters for constructing a histogram. For now I construct histograms from samples of data and then compare them to their underlying probability density functions.

This is all going well, but I don't understand what the E or 'expected value' given in MISE equations stands for. The value can be seen on the MISE [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_integrated_squared_error) or more formally in kernel density estimation sources such as [page 194 here](http://www.hep.caltech.edu/%7Efcp/statistics/densityEst/densityEst.pdf).

In most published papers the expected value E is not defined at all, and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) is not particularly helpful for me. It seems to be the average value of something, but what? The histogram?

Thanks for any help,

M.

Comment: Note that you are comparing two PDFs at multiple points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to get a good measure of the difference you take the “average” over all x. They are using t the L2 norm to determine this “average” which is just the integration over x of the squared differences

Comment: So the E here is just symbolic because the integration of squared error is a form of average? Sorry if this is obvious, I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Your empirical cdf/pdf is a random variable because it depends on the sample. The first integration is with respect to the random variable $X$ the second integration is with respect to the random variable $\hat{f_n}$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237370/how-to-calculate-mise-mean-integrated-squared-error/2338673

Comment: Hmm, I read over the discussion in your link and I still don't fully understand, sorry! Yes, the empirical pdf is a random variable because it depends on the sample. What do you mean by the first or second integration though? I only see one step of integration.

Comment: Your confusion might be from what the $E$ operator does. Let $X$ be a random variable with respective pdf $f$ then $E[X]=\int xf(x)dx$ essentially the center of mass of your distribution. Since you empirical distribution is a random variable (if you were to sample n observations multiple times each would produce a different empirical pdf) then  you can take its expected value that is why they have the  expected  value which is essentially and integration

Comment: The hard part is identifying the distribution of your empirical pdf